# $1+p$ is an element of order $p^{n-1}$ in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have seen this problem:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $n$ be a positive integer. Use the Binomial Theorem to show that $(1+p)^{p^{n-1}}\equiv 1 \mod p^n$ but $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}}\not\equiv 1 \mod p^n$. Deduce that $1+p$ is an element of order $p^{n-1}$ in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

be posted but no one has given a complete answer for the last part:

> Deduce that $1+p$ is an element of order $p^{n-1}$ in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Can someone give an explanation for how this comes from the previous part?

Comment: Do you know what is the definition of the *order of an element* in a group?

Comment: Yes. So order of $(1+p)^m=1$ where $m$ is the smallest integer to achieve this. So what I need is to show there is no $m$ smaller than $p^{n-1}$ to achieve this.

Comment: Well, you know that $(1+p)^m=1$ in $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ iff the order of $1+p$ *divides* $m$?

Comment: That's true. But how do I get that?

Comment: Let $m$ be the order of $1+p$ in $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$. Then, as $(1+p)^{p^{n-1}} = 1$ in $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ we have that $m$ divides $p^{n-1}$, so $m=p^k$ for some $k \in \{0,\dots,n-1\}$. Then what does $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}} \neq 1$ in $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$ tells you?

Comment: None of the other smaller powers of p create this =1$?

Comment: If $(1+p)^{p^j} = 1$ for some $j$, then of course $(1+p)^{p^k} = 1$ for all $k \geq j$, since $(1+p)^{p^k} = \big( (1+p)^{p^j} \big)^{p^{k-j}}$.

Comment: Alright. I get that. But how does this exclude when $k=0,...,n-3$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last question :( I mean, $j$ cannot be less than $n-1$, since that would imply that $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}}=1$: again, note that $$(1+p)^{p^{n-2}} = \big( (1+p)^{p^j} \big)^{p^{(n-2)-j}}.$$

Comment: I think I get it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Claim 1: Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be any two positive integers such that $(1+p)^{r_1} \equiv_{p^n} (1+p)^{r_2} \equiv_{p^n} 1$. Now let $r=\gcd(r_1,r_2)$. Then $(1+p)^r \equiv_{p^n} 1$ as well.

> Claim 2: Let $r$ be an integer satisfying $(1+p)^r \equiv_{p^n} 1$. Then $(1+p)^{mr} \equiv_{p^n} 1$ for any integer $m$ as well.

Let us suppose that there is a smaller positive integer $r_1 < p^{n-1}$ that satisfies
$(1+p)^{r_2} \equiv_{p^n} 1$. Now $r_2|(p-1)p^{n-1}$ [recall that $|(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^x| = (p-1)p^{n-1}$] so $r_2$ has to be either of the form
$r= cp^j$ for some integer $j < n-1$ and some integer $c$ that divides $p-1$; $c$ may be 1. But then in either case, as $p$ is prime,
$\gcd(r_1,r_2) = p^j \doteq r$. So Claim 1 gives $(1+p)^{p^j} \equiv_{p^{n}} 1$.
Then as $j < n-1$, Claim 2 gives $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}} \equiv_{p^n} 1$ as well. But this contradicts what you discovered earlier, that  $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}} \not \equiv_{p^n} 1$ after all.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder why the problem says deduce when you have to do more than a one line justification. Any ways, I wanted to ask if you think I should also prove claim 1 and 2 as part of my proof?

Answer (score 0):

Define $\pi$ and $f$, respectively, on $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ by $f(x,y)=(\pi(x,y),y+1)$ and $$(1+xp^y)^p=1+\pi(x,y)p^{y+1}\;\;\;\;\;;\;\;\;\;\;\pi(x,y)=\sum_{r=1}^p\frac{\binom{p}{r}}{p}x^rp^{y(r-1)}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$ Letting $\pi_n(x,y)$ denote the   first coordinate of $f^n(x,y)$ we must have $$(1+xp^y)^{p^n}=1+\pi_n(x,y)\cdot p^{y+n}$$ where $f^n:=f\circ\cdots\circ f\;\;\text{(n copies of $f$)}$ denotes the function composition of $n$ copies of $f$. $$\therefore\;(1+p)^{p^{n-1}}=1+\pi_{n-1}(1,1)\cdot p^n\equiv 1\mod{p^n}$$